# nginx, sticky session and IIS

Tags: iis, nginx, load-balancing

I am using nginx as the load balancer and IIS to server asp.net pages. However I am having trouble figuring out how to set sticky session in nginx. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Upstream](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule) module does this. In `http` section:

```
upstream app {
  ip_hash;

  server backend1;
  server backend2;
}
```

In your location:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://app;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is correct, to include `ip_hash;` in your upstream configuration, but I wanted to add, do not `fair;` or `weight` or other configurations in upstream as they can conflict with the ip_hashing... If you need sticky sessions based on something other than the IP of the visitor, time to go looking...

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpUpstreamModule